# Change useState's from remote component

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-state

I know with the following code below changing a useState within another component's onPress event wouldn't be possible but how would I do it? I want to make it so when the `onPress` function within `Card.js` is executed the `popUpData` from within `App.js` is changed.

App.js

```js
const [popUpData, setPopUpData] = React.useState("Nothing")

return (
   <Card>
     <Text style={styles.pokemonName}>{item.name}</Text>
   </Card>

   <Text>{popUpData}</Text>
)
```

Card.js

```js
const doSomething = () => {
   setPopUpData("Something")

   //other things...
}

return (
   <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.card} onPress={doSomething()}>
       <View style={styles.cardContent}>
           { props.children }
       </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js

```
const [popUpData, setPopUpData] = React.useState("Nothing")

return (
   <Card onUpdate={(d)=>setPopUpData(d) }>
     <Text style={styles.pokemonName}>{item.name}</Text>
   </Card>

   <Text>{popUpData}</Text>
)
```

Card.js

```
function Card(props){
 const doSomething = () => {
   props.onUpdate("Something")
 
 }

return (
   <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.card} onPress={doSomething()}>
       <View style={styles.cardContent}>
           { props.children }
       </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass reference to setState function down to child component.
(in the simplest scenario)

```js
const Parent = () => {
   const [popUpData, setPopUpData] = React.useState("Nothing")

   return (
      <Card setPopUpDataHandler={setPopUpData}>
        <Text style={styles.pokemonName}>{item.name}</Text>
       </Card>

       <Text>{popUpData}</Text>
   )
}
```

```js
const Card = ({setPopUpDataHandler, children}) => {
   const doSomething = () => {
      setPopUpDataHandler("Something")

      //other things...
   }

   return (
       <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.card} onPress={doSomething()}>
          <View style={styles.cardContent}>
              { children }
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   )
}
```